# How to set font color inside outlook email body using c#.net windows application

Tags: c#, html, fonts, outlook

I am sending mail to outlook using c#.net windows application. I need to set a font color for few lines inside the email body. I tried in several ways but could not come out with a solution. Here is my code:

body += "
Confidentiality and Disclaimer:";

I also tried like this:
body += "
Confidentiality and Disclaimer:";

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Thanks,
Ripon

Comment: You can apply custom styles to an email body via HTML. It's a general task and you can easily find any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use html tags inside your body

```
body="<font style='color:red'>something</font>something too";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways for setting the body of Outlook items:

1. The Body property (a plain text).
2. The HTMLBody property - allows to customize the body using the HTML markup as shown above.
3. The Word object model. Outlook uses Word as an email editor by default. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class which represents the body.

You can read more about these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx).

As you may see only the last two allows to do your task done.